# python assigning a list to a dictionary returns empty list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an issue whereby my list frameChain is being reflected as empty (`[]`). `frameChain` is actually a list such as: `['C Level', 'Medium Term']`

```
jsonOut[x]= {'TEXT' : node.attrib['TEXT'],
             'ID': node.attrib['ID'],
             'Sessions' : frameChain,}
```

I have tried this outside of the function I defined and it seemed to work just fine.  Any ideas as to why this would be different here?

`x` is just a counter to denote the index of the outer dictionary.

Comment: We're gonna have to see more code bro.

Comment: "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess."

Comment: The problem lies before this point in your code. A few things to try and debug: If you `print frameChain` immediately before that line, is it correct? If so, the `frameChain` list object might be shared being modified (also try `print id(frameChain)` - the number printed should change each time)

Comment: WOW guys.  This is awesome! Been a long time user of stackoverflow but have never actually asked anything.  so i solved the problem by assigning a list like so:  ['']*len(frameChain).  Then looping through and assigning each value independently.  for m, frame in enumerate(frameChain): --- and --- jsonOut[x]['Sessions'][m] =  frameChain[m].  Not sure why this is different, but not going to argue

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you were probably modifying the list after adding it to the dictionary. In python, almost everything, eg. variable names, list items, dictionary items, etc. just refer to values, and do not contain them per se. Lists are mutable, so if you add one to a dictionary and later modify the list thorough the another name, the changes show up in the dictionary too.

That is:

```
# Both names refer to the same list
a = [1]
b = a    # make B refer to the same list than A
a[0] = 2 # modify the list that both A and B now refer to
print a  # prints: [2]
print b  # prints: [2]

# The value in the dictionary refers to the same list as A
a = [1]
b = {'key': a}
a[0] = 2
print a # prints: [2]
print b # prints: {'key': [2]}
```

However, note that assigning a new value to a variable does not change the referred value:

```
# Names refer to different lists
a = [1]
b = a   # make B refer to the same list than A
a = [2] # make A refer to a new list
print a # prints [2]
print b # prints [1]
```

You created a new list and copied the items "manually" from the old list to the new one one-by-one. That works, but it takes up a lot of space, and there's a simpler way to do it by using slicing. Slicing returns a new list, so if you don't specify the start and end positions, ie. by writing `list_variable[:]`, it essentially just returns a copy of the original list.

That is, modifying the original examples:

```
# Names refer to different lists
a = [1]
b = a[:] # make B refer to a copy of the list that A refers to
a[0] = 2
print a  # prints: [2]
print b  # prints: [1]

# The value in the dictionary refers to a different list than A
a = [1]
b = {'key': a[:]}
a[0] = 2
print a # prints: [2]
print b # prints: {'key': [1]}
```